# How to convert Mssql query into LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I convert this query into LINQ expression?

```
WITH MyRowSet
AS
(
SELECT  RH.Id,RH.Reputation,RH.ReputationIpId,CheckDateTime,IpGroup.Name,ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY ReputationIpId ORDER BY CheckDateTime DESC) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.ReputationHistory As RH
INNER JOIN dbo.ReputationIps as IP ON RH.ReputationIpId=IP.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.ReputationMonitorGroups as IpGroup ON IP.ReputationMonitorGroupId=IpGroup.Id
)
SELECT AVG(Reputation),Name RowNum FROM MyRowSet WHERE RowNum <= 5  Group By RowNum,Name ORDER BY RowNum
```

What is this query doing?
It takes five last "Reputation" record for each "IP" in history
and then we get the average value for IpGroup.

First part of expression is:

```
reputationHistoryRepository.GetAll()
                .GroupBy(el => el.ReputationIpId)
                .Select(grp => grp
                    .OrderBy(gr => gr.CheckDateTime)
                    .TakeLast(lastRecordNum))
```

It takes last 5 records for each IP. Then I need to get the average value for each row. For example average value for the first row of all IPs, second and so on.

Comment: lastRecordNum= 5 (by default) - get last 5 . Forgot to describe this variable.

Comment: What isn't working?   I usually do the joins using (from a in b join c in d on a.s equal c.t select new {a = a, c = c}).Select(x => ..............)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this. Here is the answer.

```
var result = _reputationHistoryRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(ips => ips.ReputationIp)
            .ThenInclude(ipGroups => ipGroups.ReputationMonitorGroup)
            .GroupBy(repHistory => repHistory.ReputationIpId)
            .Select(group => group
                .OrderBy(repHistory => repHistory.CheckDateTime)
                .TakeLast(countOfRecords)
                .Select((reputationHistory, index) => new
                {
                    GroupName = reputationHistory.ReputationIp.ReputationMonitorGroup.Name,
                    ReputationHistoryObject = reputationHistory,
                    RowNum = index
                }))
            .SelectMany(reputationHistory => reputationHistory)
            .GroupBy(reputationHistory => new
            {
                reputationHistory.RowNum,
                reputationHistory.GroupName
            })
            .Select(reputationHistoryGroup => new
            {
                Reputation = reputationHistoryGroup.Average(x => x.ReputationHistoryObject.Reputation),
                GrpName = reputationHistoryGroup.Key.GroupName,
                RowNum = reputationHistoryGroup.Key.RowNum
            });
```